# django dynamic form save data

Tags: python, django, forms, dynamic-forms

thanks for reading this post and offering help to me.

I am new to Django and I am working on a website for aboriginal regions to record their lives. Users can create a page and publish contents. Before they create a page, they need to specify the number of seasons that they want to record. The website will base on the number of seasons to dynamically create textfields.

Currently, I can dynamically create textfields, but I have problems saving the data. I spent a long time trying to solve this issue but still stuck at here. The mistake I got is 'SeasonalTextForm' object has no attribute 'instance'.

article that I am following when I implemented the dynamic form:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c52yK.jpg) https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/
[2] https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/05/07/creating-dynamic-forms-django/

Here is the error message(the image can only attach as a link):
[Attribute Error: 'SeasonalTextForm' object has no attribute 'instance'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c52yK.jpg)

Here is my model.py

```
class PageComponent(models.Model):
    componentName=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, verbose_name="Name")
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AS_User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    page = models.ForeignKey(CommunityPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    STATUS = (
        ('a', 'Activated'),
        ('d', 'Deactivated'),
    )

    componentStatus=models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=STATUS,
        blank=False,
        default='d',
        help_text='the current status of the page component', editable=False
    )

    textContent=models.TextField(max_length=10000, help_text="Enter a description for your component", null=True, blank=True)
    photoContent=models.ImageField(upload_to=component_directory_path, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Photo")
    # videoContent=models.VideoField(upload_to=component_directory_path, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Video")

class PageComponent_SeasonalText(models.Model):
    pageStextComponent = models.ForeignKey(PageComponent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seasonalText = models.CharField(max_length=10001)
```

Here is my form.py:

```
class SeasonalTextForm(forms.Form):
    componentName = forms.CharField(label=_('Enter title'),max_length=40)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        seasonTexts = kwargs.pop('extra')
        # super(SeasonalTextForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        super(SeasonalTextForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # seasonTexts = PageComponent_SeasonalText.objects.filter(pageStextComponent = pageStextComponent)

        for i in range(seasonTexts):
            field_name = 'seasonText_%s' % (i,)
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':10, 'cols':51}))
        #set field label as placeholder for every field
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs["placeholder"] = field.label
        # field_name = 'seasonText_%s' % (i+1,)
        # self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':10, 'cols':51}))
        # self.fields[field_name]=""

    def clean(self):
        seasonTexts = set()
        i = 0
        field_name = 'seasonText_%s'% (i,)
        while self.cleaned_data.get(field_name):
            seasonText = self.cleaned_data[field_name]
            if seasonText in seasonTexts:
                self.add_error(field_name, 'Duplicate')
            else:
                seasonTexts.add(seasonText)
            i += 1
            field_name='seasonText_%s' % (i,)
        self.cleaned_data["seasonTexts"] = seasonTexts

    def save(self):
        PageComponent = self.instance
        PageComponent.save()
        PageComponent.componentName = self.cleaned_data["componentName"]
        # pageStextComponent.seasonText_set.all().delete()
        for seasonalText in self.cleaned_data["seasonTexts"]:
            PageComponent_SeasonalText.objects.create(
                pageStextComponent = PageComponent.pageStextComponent,
                seasonalText = seasonalText,
            )

    def get_seasonText_fields(self):
        for field_name in self.fields:
            if field_name.startswith('seasonText'):
                yield self[field_name]
```

Here is my view.py:

```
def SeasonalText(request, page_id, id):
    page = get_object_or_404(CommunityPage, pk=page_id)
    as_user = get_object_or_404(AS_User, pk=id)
    # s_component = get_object_or_404(PageComponent, pk=cid)
    numOfSeasons = page.numSeasons
    form = SeasonalTextForm(request.POST, extra=numOfSeasons)
    # sTexts = PageComponent_SeasonalText.objects.filter(pageComponent_id=s_component)
    # form = SeasonalTextForm(request.POST, extra=sTexts)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # my_user = AS_User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            # my_type = Type.objects.get(id=4)
            # PageComponent.user = my_user
            # PageComponent.page = page
            # PageComponent.type = my_type
            # PageComponent.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('page', kwargs={'page_id':page_id}))
    else:
        form = SeasonalTextForm(extra=numOfSeasons)
    return render(request, 'communityPages/Stext_component.html', {'form':form, 'page':page, 'id':as_user})
```

Comment: This is the wrong approach. Since you want to create a number of instances, you should use a formset, which takes care of all this for you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman hi Daniel, what if I don't want to create a number of instances? What is the meaning of creating instances? I did that is because the example did so and I cannot find an alternative method to change that. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: What? I mean instances of PageComponent_SeasonalText. Creating a number of those is *exactly* what you are trying to do. A modelformset will take care of that for you. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Comment: Hello ken-choi, Try use formset, if you want i can post you answer, but firstly you must read a doc for formset use.

Comment: @rakwen I've read the document and try two examples online but still cannot apply the principle to my case. It would be great if you have time to help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: I have time ! But explain me clearly wath do want to do step by step ...

Comment: @rakwen, I am following this tutorial :https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d. What I currently have is the model.py and form.py get done. But I am not sure how to do the view.py as the tutorial use many functions that I am not familiar

Comment: @rakwen, I also want to know, am I need to use "inlineformset_factory"? in the tutorial, profile and family members have dependent relation. In my case, it is same. That's why I choose this tutorial but it seems not implementing in a normal way.

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html...It is same method but more explained

Comment: @rakwen, thanks for the link. I am looking it.

Comment: Use this : https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html#what-does-a-formset-do

Comment: @rakwen thanks a lot for your help! I am getting there. Can I ask how can I pass a value to extra in formset? I want the value of extra is dynamic rathan than interact with the button. Here is the code of my formset: SeasonalTextFormSet = formset_factory(SeasonalTextForm, extra=1)

Comment: Sorry i'm not connect. If i understand you want to change extra param of formset dynamicaly ? It is right ?

Comment: yes. that's what I want. not change by the UI add/remove button, but by value past from other class.@rakwen